# Changing Color of Panel to match Users Theme Color

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, colors

How can I set the BackgroundColor of a Control (Panel) so that it is the same Color as my user's Windows Theme Color?

I found this:
[Changing Theme(Color) of a panel according to Windows themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389371/changing-themecolor-of-a-panel-according-to-windows-themes)

And I'm sorry, but I don't think those answerer's even bothered to check what they said. Setting the Control's BackgroundColor to Control, does not make it the same color as the Theme Color. It simply gives it a nice Gray-ish looking color.

I want to know what Color the Glass is in Windows Vista/7. How can I get this info at runtime?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the background color of your `Panel` so it matches the window color defined in the theme, you can do:

```
yourPanel.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
```

To obtain the glass color on Windows Vista and higher, you have to p/invoke [DwmGetColorizationColor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969513.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for the link and snip @Frédéric - much appreciated! :)